# React app running in docker container is crashing (EMFILE: too many open files)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, file-descriptor

My docker container serving the front end (react) of my application in production is crashing

```
{"log":"Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open '/ui/build/static/css/main.9c502893.chunk.css'\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2021-08-23T11:31:39.794522183Z"}
```

It seems to be caused by node keeping static files opened :

in `/proc/61/fd` :

```
lr-x------    1 root     root            64 Aug 24 08:30 91 -> /ui/build/images/vertical-life-project-owner.jpg
lr-x------    1 root     root            64 Aug 24 08:30 910 -> /ui/build/icons/deckchair.png
lr-x------    1 root     root            64 Aug 24 08:30 9100 -> /ui/build/static/js/main.f38b6972.chunk.js
lr-x------    1 root     root            64 Aug 24 08:30 9101 -> /ui/build/static/css/3.3b09fbf6.chunk.css
lr-x------    1 root     root            64 Aug 24 08:30 9102 -> /ui/build/static/css/main.9c502893.chunk.css
lr-x------    1 root     root            64 Aug 24 08:30 9103 -> /ui/build/static/js/3.d81cf15a.chunk.js
lr-x------    1 root     root            64 Aug 24 08:30 9104 -> /ui/build/videos/home.mp4
lr-x------    1 root     root            64 Aug 24 08:30 9105 -> /ui/build/static/js/main.f38b6972.chunk.js
lr-x------    1 root     root            64 Aug 24 08:30 9106 -> /ui/build/static/js/0.a1e638a1.chunk.js
lr-x------    1 root     root            64 Aug 24 08:30 9107 -> /ui/build/static/js/6.f8fd35f0.chunk.js
lr-x------    1 root     root            64 Aug 24 08:30 9108 -> /ui/build/manifest.json
lr-x------    1 root     root            64 Aug 24 08:30 9109 -> /ui/build/logo192.png
...
```

The `ulimit` of my server is reached, when enough files are open (I have 5000 users a day on my app so it occurs quickly), causing this docker container to crash

I tried the following :

- Add header Cache Control on static ressources
- Upgrading node version (12, 13.13.0, 14.17.5)
- Adding `--ulimit nofile=20000:25000` on my docker run command
- Augment `ulimit` on my server
- Use `graceful-fs`

but nothing worked, those files keep remaining opened.

My app is served with this script in `package.json` :
`"deployment": "export NODE_ENV=production && serve -s build -l 5002"`

runned by this dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.17.5-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /ui

ENV PATH /ui/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY ui /ui

COPY builds/production/.env /ui/.env

RUN yarn add package.json --silent
RUN yarn run build

CMD yarn run deployment
```

Comment: What are you using to serve the production build?

Comment: @Matt I'm using this command :
`export NODE_ENV=production && serve -s build -l 5002`

Comment: I added the dockerfile in my question